# Project creation using GWT+maven(gwt-maven-plugin) compiles following error,normal GWT project creation(without maven)compiles good(luna,GWT sdk2.6)

Tags: gwt, eclipse-juno, eclipse-luna, gwt-maven-plugin

This is the exception while project compilation, The environment is ubuntu 14.01LTS,
ECLIPSE LUNA, also eclipse Juno, gwt-eclipse-plugin, Java 1.7,

But it compiles good when i was creating without maven project(New project - > google gwt)

```
Loading inherited module 'com.***.***.Application'
   Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.user.User'
      Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
     Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.CompilerParameters'
        [WARN] Setting configuration property named compiler.max.vars.per.var in com.google.gwt.core.CompilerParameters that has not been previously defined.  This may be disallowed in the future.
Compiling module com.***.***.Application
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.writeEnumValueOfMethod(GwtAstBuilder.java:2839)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.processEnumType(GwtAstBuilder.java:2488)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.endVisit(GwtAstBuilder.java:1921)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.endVisit(GwtAstBuilder.java:1604)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1311)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.process(GwtAstBuilder.java:3131)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:470)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:880)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:511)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:434)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:420)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:485)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:241)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:223)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:139)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:99)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:106)
```

Please tell me what would be reason for this,
Thanks in advance!
Thangaraj

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Maven, but try to delete the 2 gwt-unitCache dirs and try compile again

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply.I don't have such a folder in my project

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error, and it seems it was because I didn't explicitly add

`<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>`

to my GWT module xml